# error C2027: the gcc vs msvc case

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2010

This simple snippet of code

```
class S;

class G
{

    void onRead(S & s)
    {
           (void)s;
    }
};
```

perfectly works on GCC. Using that `(void)s` is a very useful way to avoid the warning "unused variable 's'". But MSVC sees this as an error, stopping the compilation.
It gives the infamous error C2027: use of undefined type 's'. But here 's' its not used at all.

How can I solve this kind of trouble?

I don't want to use the form of `void onRead(S &)` because you can't see it in this little snippet example, but in my code that 's' name is really meaningful, and useful to understand the parameters.

Comment: You can solve this by defining the body of onRead in a `.cpp` file (not in the header).

Comment: "that 's' name is really meaningful, and useful to understand the parameters" - that's what docs/comments are for.

Comment: I know Mat, but this code is internal code, it is not documented, and never will be. I just want a simple way to pass by this MSVC quirk.

Comment: Holt, the problem is that class hasn't a `.cpp` file, is an header-only class

Comment: Q: How can a the name of a parameter that is not used be *really meaningful, and useful to understand the parameters*?

Comment: @MarcoPagliaricci: You can still provide the definition of the function outside of the class definition and leave it unnamed there

Comment: As I said before, it is just an header-only template class, but the real matter I was wondering about was the non-portability between gcc and msvc of that `(void)s;` method. If you use that, with gcc will work and with msvc won't. This was the real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of alternate ways of avoiding the error.

The most straight-forward is to convert the variable name to a comment:

```
void onRead(S & /* s */)
```

Another is to use a macro to remove the variable:

```
#define UNUSED(x)

void onRead(S & UNUSED(s))
```

I'm sure you've already thought of just moving the code to a point where `S` is fully defined and there's some reason you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I wanted to avoid this redudancy such as using macros or /* */ but it seems the only way.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "s" because the class "S" hasn't been fully defined.  You can:

1) Disable the warning with #pragma warning(disable:4100)

2) Move the body of the `onRead` function to a place where "S" has been fully defined

3) Move the definition of "S" so it is before `onRead`

4) Use a void pointer: `(void*)&s;`

Comment: unfortunately 'error C2027' is an error and not a warning. But moving the body of the `onRead` would definitely fix that, thanks.

Comment: I believe the snippet in the question is actually well-formed C++. You are allowed to have references to incomplete types, and cast to `void` does not cause lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless the lvalue is `volatile`.

Comment: @MarcoPagliaricci whoops, of course it is an error there, I guess I had a bit of a brain moment, sorry!

Comment: @MarcoPagliaricci actually what I meant was to use the `#pragma` to remove the "unused variable" warning

Comment: @MarcoPagliaricci I just found another way of doing it... instead of casting it to `(void)`, take its address and cast it to `(void*)`.  I have updated my answer accordingly.